# Line break after back button - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin forms and have directed to a navigation page from my main page, I'd like the title to appear on the same line as the back button but it's currently appearing on the line below, like this -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/glcXR.png

I am using the following code to display the title -

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="About" TextColor="{StaticResource lightGreen}">
            <Label.FontFamily>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                                Android="GothamRoundedMedium.ttf#GothamRoundedMedium"
                                iOS="GothamRoundedMedium">
                </OnPlatform>
            </Label.FontFamily>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

and this code to navigate to the about page -

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new Survey2()));
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you have one NavigationPage nested inside of another - don't do that.  Just do Navigation.PushAsync(new Survey2());

Comment: That worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With `new NavigationPage` you are again creating a new NavigationPage.

So,just use:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new Survey2());
```

If you need to use Modal,use this:

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new Survey2()));
```